# como oculto un token de la api de instagram en mi proyecto en node

Tags: api, seguridad, tokens, instagram

tengo un repositorio publico en git, estoy haciendo un fetch a la api de instagram, guarde el token en un .env pero me bloquean el token porque es peligroso, me funciona solo si hago privado el repo, pero quiero que sea publico, que deberia hacer para solucionar este problema de seguridad?

Comment: En tu archivo .gitignore agrega .env para que cuando hagas push a tu proyecto, no se guarde ese token, de otro modo tendrás que hacerlo privado hasta que finalices tu proyecto.

Comment: ya lo hice eso pero me lo toma igual como falla de seguridad y me bloquea el token, por eso pregunto si hay otra manera